# Game Maker Studio json_encode encodes 0 as -1.#IND00

Tags: json, list, game-maker

I have quite a complicated structure of lists with lists inside, which i encode to JSON in order to save the game, and then decode it back.

I was certain all works fine, but then suddenly, one of the zeros is encoded as -1.#IND00

During the particular test I found it out, there were five lists of the same class as this, and only the final one ended up encoded in a wrong way.

code:

```
 for(var zG=0; zG<ds_list_size(global.wojny); zG++){
    var j_map=ds_map_create();
    ds_map_add_list(j_map, "provinces", global.wojny[|zG]);
    global.wojny[|zG] = json_encode(j_map);
    ds_map_destroy(j_map);
}
```

full encoded list:
[8th element saves as -1.#IND00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHrx1.png)

```
"{ "provinces": [ 9.000000, 0.000000, 9.000000, "{ \"countries1\": [ ] }", 
"{ \"countries2\": [ ] }", 0.000000, 0.000000, 9991.000000, -1.#IND00, 
100.000000, 13983.000000, 13984.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000 ] }"
```

a similar list, saved properly in the same for using the same code

```
"{ "provinces": [ 5.000000, 8.000000, 3.000000, "{ \"countries1\": [ ] }",
 "{ \"countries2\": [ ] }", 169.000000, 184.000000, 8614.000000, 128.000000,
 66.666667, 8626.000000, 8627.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000 ] }"
```

[a list that is encoded properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9mAZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how to hot fix it - that particular value was a result of mathematical calculations that took place throughout the game, it started as 100 and got reduced to 0 by subtracting real values from it.
My hot fix was to include this into the for before encoding it to json:

```
var zGwojnapom = global.wojny[|zG];
    zGwojnapom[|8] = round(real(zGwojnapom[|8]));
```